# Java: How to call a method from an object thats in an arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm new to java so if someone could explain it simply that would be great. This is also in android studio By the way. I get an error whenever I try to do this.

```
int next = 0;
public class Outlaw {
    String name;
    String message;
    public Outlaw(String name, String message){

    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }



}

Outlaw outlaw0;
Outlaw outlaw1;
Outlaw outlaw2;
Outlaw outlaw3;
Outlaw outlaw4;
Outlaw outlaw5;
Outlaw outlaw6;
Outlaw outlaw7;
ArrayList<Outlaw> outlaws;


public void continueFunct(View view){
    Log.i("outlaws",outlaws.get(0).getMessage());
    if (step == 0){
        step =+ 1;
        infoTextView.setText(outlaws.get(0).getMessage());
    } else if (step == 1){

        show();
        next =+ 1;

    }

}
```

And then I have this in the onCreate method

```
 outlaws = new ArrayList<>();
    outlaw0 = new Outlaw("Trader Joe", "You caught Trader Joe selling faulty Lemons!");
    outlaw1 = new Outlaw("Dirty Dan", "\"No I'm Dirty Dan!\"");
    outlaw2 = new Outlaw("Itchy Trigger", "Well, Well, Well, if it isn't Itchy Trigger");
    outlaw3 = new Outlaw("Eye-Twitch Bill", "Agh! A monster! Oh never mind it's just Eye-Twitch Bill");
    outlaw4 = new Outlaw("Skinny Pete", "Sooo we meet again Skinny Pete");
    outlaw5 = new Outlaw("Whiskey Larry", "A drunken whiskey Larry stumbles into view");
    outlaw6 = new Outlaw("Alamo Jack", "A new challenger approaches! Alamo Jack!");
    outlaw7 = new Outlaw("El Loco", "\"That was my amigo! You will pay for what you have done!\"");
    outlaws.add(outlaw0);
    outlaws.add(outlaw1);
    outlaws.add(outlaw2);
    outlaws.add(outlaw3);
    outlaws.add(outlaw4);
    outlaws.add(outlaw5);
    outlaws.add(outlaw6);
    outlaws.add(outlaw7);
```

I know I have all the write frameworks imported but I keep getting errors whenever I click the continue button. When I get rid of the log statement, the textView i'm trying to set just goes blank, with the Log statement the app crashes.

This is the error message I get, not sure what to do with it exactly maybe it will help.

```
05-26 20:44:08.826 21384-21384/com.scottolsonofficial.westventure E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.scottolsonofficial.westventure, PID: 21384
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:164)
    at com.scottolsonofficial.westventure.MainActivity.continueFunct(MainActivity.java:106)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: If you're seeing errors and are asking how to fix them, you'll want to post the full error message with your question (edit the question -- don't post it in comments) and indicate where in your code they occur.

Comment: I added it, not sure how to indicate where in my code it occurs. I'm pretty new to this, this is my first time asking a question on hear.

Comment: Use debugger to check this line: `Log.i("outlaws",outlaws.get(0).getMessage());` if the `getMessage()` are null [Edited]

Comment: @TuyenNguyen If `outlaws.get(0)` were null, we'd never see `Log.i` on the stack trace.

Comment: Your `Outlaw` constructor doesn't do anything.  I think you want to set your instance variables.  But you don't.  So `message` is null, and `getMessage()` returns null.

Comment: So what do i do then, I'm new, I don't know what an instance variable even is.

Comment: Please try to learn some Java before diving into Android

Comment: I'm taking a course right now. But I thought I would create something myself sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to assign the fields of your class.

Your constructor currently does nothing, and thus `getMessage()` returns `null` as it was never assigned.

```
public class Outlaw {
    private String name;
    private String message;
    public Outlaw(String name, String message){
        this.name = name;
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your getMessage function is returning a null object.

Another part of your code seems to be modifying the message. I would declare the message as

```
final String message;
```

This will ensure that otger parts of the code cant mess with it

Comment: This just rephrased the stacktrace, what's the solution?

Comment: The offending code was clearly posted... Please refer accepted answer

Comment: i didn't put the "this.name = name;" part, i understand that now

Comment: Ideally, don't use final if setters are planned on being used

Comment: You are right. But in this case, he didnt have setters and i was just suggesting he do this to diagnose the problem.